# X server failed to start after using nvidia-xconfig and unable to use my 2nd GPU anyhow

Tags: nvidia, xorg, wine

I installed bumbulbee drivers by running the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic
```

and then checked the configuration by running:

```
sudo optirun nvidia-settings -c :8
```

and checked for all the setting which appeared fine. But then when I rebuilt the `xorg.conf` file by running:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
restart lightdm
```

and after that when I restarted the system. X server failed to start resulting in blank screen. When tried starting Xserver by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, `startx` failed to start (gives the error), so when I removed `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` the system started off well again but it seems that when ever I try to run Counter Strike 1.6 by `optirun` through `wine` by:

```
env WINEPREFIX="/home/ph3n1x/.wine" optirun wine C:\\"Program Files"\\"Counter-Strike 1.6"\\hl.exe
```

it fails with the error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  135 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  26 (X_GLXMakeContextCurrent)
Serial number of failed request:  254
Current serial number in output stream:  254
```

My `lspci` shows:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation Device 1058 (rev ff)
```

So I can't figure out what exactly is the problem and what can be the solution to it. Please any help.

Comment: Run the game with the HL.exe and switch to Counter Strike then modify the video setting to 32bit 1024x768 resolution it will work flawless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had to change the ownership of the file .Xauthority . 
I went through a cycle of failure when a screen saver locked up my X server. I killed the session, re-booted, and the desktop refused to start *for my account only*. I started another account, opened a terminal and changed to my account using the 'su' command:

```
su - myaccount
```

I could log in as myself.

### THE KEY DIAGNOSIS

I looked at my home directory -

```
ls -lrt |tail
```

> -rw-------  1 root    root       107 Feb 17 10:16 .Xauthority

and found that the .Xauthority account was owned by root.

### **To Change ownership of a file**

I changed the ownership with

`sudo chown myaccount:myaccount .Xauthority`

I confirmed the ownership change with ' ls -lrt |tail ' and then logged in as myself.

> -rw-------  1 myaccount    myaccount       107 Feb 17 10:16 .Xauthority

**All better!**

Typically files that begin with a dot and in your home directory should belong to yourself. AND you would **never** log in as root, right?

Comment: Well the problem of not being able to login was easily solved as I simply just deleted my `Xauthority` file and rebooted the real problem is that although at every single point my system is recognizing my 2nd GPU - nVIDIA 630m but when I try to default start my `X server` with it,it simply crashes and refuse to start. More with that I am not able use my GPU even by the optirun run command.